# Inserting fake rows into an HBase table in order to use them as a startrow with a PrefixFilter for optimizing reads

Tags: hbase

In HBase, rowkeys are stored in sorted order. A scan with a `PrefixFilter` will do a full table scan on the index until it finds a match. After the match ends, the scan will terminate. A common solution to preventing the full table scan is provide a `startrow` in combination with the PrefixFilter. **However, this won't work if you don't know the `startrow` in advance.**

Say you have a template like the following:

```
<foo>|<bar>|<baz>|
```

I'm thinking of adding a bunch of fake rows that I can use as the `startrow`.

For example, take the following row keys:

```
a|
a|b|c|
a|d|e|
a|f|g|
b|
b|b|c|
b|d|e|
b|f|g|
```

Here, rows `a|` and `b|` are "fake rows" who exist solely to optimize the query:

```
scan 'tab', {STARTROW => 'b|', FILTER => "PrefixFilter('b')"}
```

Will this strategy work as intended?

Comment: Don't need to actually add it to table, but just assign it to the filter when you want to scan..